# Transform rows to columns by the values of two rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset which has two columns  `Name, Value` and it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['code',10],['classe',12],['series','B'], ['code',12],['classe',1],
['series','C'],['code',16],['classe',18],['series','A']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Value'])
df1
```

Output

```
    Name    Value
0   code    10
1   classe  12
2   series  B
3   code    12
4   classe  1
5   series  C
6   code    16
7   classe  18
8   series  A
```

And I want some thing like that:

```
    code  classe series
0   10      10    B
1   12      1     C
2   16      18    A
```

In my dataset it reapts N time and i want to transform it to three columns `code, classe, series`.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.concat` with a `groupby` should do it.

```
pd.concat([
     pd.Series(v.values, name=k) for k, v in df1.groupby('Name')['Value']
   ], 
   axis=1
)

  classe code series
0     12   10      B
1      1   12      C
2     18   16      A
```

---

**Option 2**
`pivot`
Flaky pivot hack, don't count on it! This solution assumes values inside `Name` alternate regularly - code, classe, series, code, classe, series, ... and so on. Won't work otherwise.

```
df1.assign(Index=df1.index // 3).pivot('Index', 'Name', 'Value')

Name  classe code series
Index                   
0         12   10      B
1          1   12      C
2         18   16      A
```

Comment: Just one question. This can be achieved also using `pivot` function ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut So there is a way, but it isn't recommended for obvious reasons ;-)

Comment: What are the reasons? @COLDSPEED

Comment: @iDrwish Format has to be regular, I've added an explanation to my answer, take a look :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I changed the order of the data inputs and it still worked!, I added the updated version, can you explain further why this won't work?

Comment: @iDrwish I'm talking about my solution, not yours.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using `.pivot`

```
df2 = df1.pivot(columns='Name', values='Value')
pd.concat([df2[series].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for series in df2], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
  classe    code    series
0   12       10     B
1   1        12     C
2   18       16     A
```

More so, if you changed the ordered data, you still get the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['code',10],['classe',12],['classe', 14], ['series','B'], ['series', 'C'], ['code',12],['classe',1],
['series','C'],['code',16],['classe',18],['series','A']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Value'])
df1

    Name    Value
0   code    10
1   classe  12
2   classe  14 #Added classe
3   series  B
4   series  C  #Added Series
5   code    12
6   classe  1
7   series  C
8   code    16
9   classe  18
10  series  A
```

The output will be:

```
   classe   code    series
0   12       10      B
1   14       12      C
2   1        16      C
3   18      NaN      A
```

Comment: You can hack around `pivot` @COLDSPEED @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut

Answer (score 2):

create a new key by using `cumsum`, then `unstack`

```
df1['new']=(df1.Name=='code').cumsum()
df1.set_index(['new','Name']).Value.unstack()
Out[80]: 
Name classe code series
new                    
1        12   10      B
2         1   12      C
3        18   16      A
```